# Telegram bot: forward old messages

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Is there any way to have a Telegram bot that forwards very old messages? Let's say that a bot has had access to a chat for 2 years, can it forward the first message it received in that chat?

From my understanding, the `forwardMessage()` function requires a `message_id` parameter which corresponds to the ID received by `getUpdates()`, which however only holds messages up to 24 hours prior to the call.

But maybe there is some other way?

Comment: You can store messages on your side (in the database) and in this case you can forward. But, sorry, I don't known any way to get old messages from chat